# Counting occurance of a number in a random number generator

Tags: java

I have this block of code which generates numbers from 0 to 9 randomly but I need to count how many times each number pops up.

```
i = new Integer(tTala.getText()).intValue();
n = 1;
j = (int)(Math.random() * 10.0);
while (n <= i) {
    j = (int)(Math.random() * 10.0);
    tTolur.append(""+ j + '\n');
    n++;
}
```

But I have no idea how to count how many times each number pops up. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: @GhostCat https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1 We're not doing that kind of commenting anymore.

Comment: @mypetlion It is not that easy ( see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366733/1531124 for example ).

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need is an array that's the same size as your random range. So something like this:

```
i = new Integer(tTala.getText()).intValue();
n = 1;
j = (int)(Math.random() * 10.0);
//
int[] tracker = new int[10]
//
while (n <= i) {
    j = (int)(Math.random() * 10.0);
    tTolur.append(""+ j + '\n');
    n++;
    //
    tracker[j]++;
    //
}
```

The array will start with values of `0`, and every time a (for example) `2` is generated, you increment the value at index `2` in your array.